# Script que actue en pagina ajena para seleccion dropdown automaticos

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, webforms, dropdownlist

soy desconocido ante lo que pregunto. ¿Es posible crear un script que rellene un formulario ajeno por mi, similar al autocompletar? Ya sea en javascript o en algún otro lenguaje el cual dada una cierta acción, entonces se seleccione automáticamente el o los dropdown de un formulario? Vale decir que estos dropdown son conocidos para mi pero no puedo intervenir la web externa en su código.

A modo de ejemplo, si aprieto un botón llamado "No contestar", entonces el script lograra conectarse con dicha web y me seleccionara un dropdown A y otro dropdown B, para luego finalizar dicha gestión de forma manual con un "enviar", sin la necesidad de estar escogiendo siempre los dropdown. Hago esto todos los días y creo que se pierde tiempo seleccionando los dropdown.

Agradezco leerme y su tiempo :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar autohotkey, el programa repite una tarea programada que hace tu PC al apretar una sola tecla, o una combinación de ellas, te dejo el link https://www.autohotkey.com, espero te sirva y saludos :)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/147451)

Comment: Cómo dejó la parte esencial de un programa mí querido amigo?

Comment: Pues ademas del link puedes escribir cuales son los pasos basicos de implementacion, tal vez condigo , imagenes, claras intrucciones, de modo que el que pregunta tenga una guia de como resolverlo.